# PDO with extended PDOStatement cannot disconnect the connection when set NULL

Tags: php, mysql, connection, pdo

Tested in PHP 5.5.22 and 5.5.25

When using PDO that has extended PDOStatement, MySQL keep connection until when PHP script are finished.

```
use PDO;

$dbinfoCode = array(
    'userid' => 'userid',
    'password' => 'password',
    'engine' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '192.168.100.2',
    'database' => 'test',
);


for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {

    $dsn = sprintf("%s:host=%s;dbname=%s", $dbinfo['engine'], $dbinfo['host'], $dbinfo['database']);

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbinfo['userid'], $dbinfo['password'], $options);
    $pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array ('PDOStatement2', array($pdo)));
    $pdo = null;

}

class PDOStatement2 extends PDOStatement {
}
```

I can see increasingly stacked "Sleep" processes on MySQL query. Finally, MySQL throw error "Too many connections".

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

If there is no setAttribute about `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS`, The MySQL connection is disconnected in working order.

```
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbinfo['userid'], $dbinfo['password'], $options);
    //$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array ('PDOStatement2', array($pdo)));
    $pdo = null;
```

I have no idea about it wheather is this a bug or has another solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

$pdo object on following statement will be duplicated

```
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array ('PDOStatement2', array($pdo)));
```

Use `&$pdo` instead of `$pdo`.

```
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array ('PDOStatement2', array(&$pdo)));
```